# Как выйти из функции при выполнении условия?

Tags: c#, unity3d

нужно сделать выход из функции. Например есть функция

```
private void events()
{
 if(//какое то условие)
 {
  // какой то код
  // выход из функции
 }
 // остальной код
}
```

которая вызывается в Update

```
private void Update()
{
 //какой то код
 events();
}
```

и нужно чтобы в функции events если выполниться условие то она бы вышла или бы скипнула итерацию как например contunie. Что можно использовать?

Comment: Где вам нужно скипнуть итерацию? Конкретизируйте вопрос, допустим выполнился метод `events`, от этого метод `Update` завершится или перейдет к следующей итерации?

Comment: Если вам нужно скип итерации делать внутри `events`, то в условии добавьте просто `return;`

Comment: например если в events выполниться 1 условие то он просто выйдет не продолжая выполнять остальной код

Comment: Остальной код - это какой? Внутри `events` или внутри `Update`?

Comment: внутри events()

Comment: Такие вопросы неприлично задавать. Что бы самому на него ответить - нужны вообще минимальные знания языка программирования. Простите, но Вам рановато работать в Unity. Для начала Вам следует укрепить свои знания C#. Иначе в дальнейшем Вы будете чаще и чаще сталкиваться с "нерешаемыми самостоятельно проблемами"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы выйти из метода можно использовать `return;` Заметьте, что если метод будет возвращать какое-то значение, то использование обычного `return;` не будет работать, компилятор потребует какое-то значение.

```
private void events()
{
    if(/*условие*/)
    {
        //код
        return;
        //код дальше не будет выполняться, произойдет выход из метода.
    }
}
```

Comment: не думал что можно использовать return без значения. спасибо

Comment: @ULYANARSL только если метод void

Comment: Один из принципов структурного программирования гласит, что все подпрограммы(в нашем случае методы) должны иметь один вход и один выход. Лучше переписать метод без явного return.

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin не всегда стоит придерживаться принципов и прочей лабуды которую напридумывали.. не вижу ничего плохого в том, что выход из метода будет по какому-то условию

Comment: @Aarnihauta это не на придумывали лабуды, а опыт топов и основателей программирования, таких как Эдсгер Дейкстра)) "не всегда стоит придерживаться принципов" - не всегда, но всегда нужно это делать осознанно и обоснованно, в данном случае обоснования нет, т.к. есть возможность обеспечить один выход из метода - это, как минимум, облегчит этапы отладки и тестирования.

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin да, определенно, стоит следовать различным паттернам, методологиям итд итп, но тут вопрос вообще про другое был) Да и у меня часто встречаются моменты когда мне нужно иметь выход из метода по условию. К примеру если мне придет пустой файл я не хочу кидать эксепшен, мне легче вернуть Enumerable.Empty или попросту null